# White screen on page load - Android only

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, galaxy

running into a interesting item that is starting to get on my nerves.

Working on WelcometoKelowna.com. Was testing on a variety of devices. Desktop + variety of browsers works as expected. iOS devices all seem to be working. However, when I tested on a Galaxy SIII, something a bit odd happens.

The page seems to load, but only a white screen shows. However, soon as the user touches, or scrolls on the page - it instantly appears.

Anyone else run into this? Browser bug? I don't see it happening on any other sites. I am a bit stumped on this one.

Comment: No one is going to spend hours trying to fix an error that is just one part of a huge site. Please provide a smaller test case.

Comment: Not asking anyone to troubleshoot. 

Just wondering in anyone has ever ran into this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and boiled it down to use of position:fixed. Switching to position:absolute solved this white screen problem.